# Jenkins pipeline regex not matching anything

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've got a regex with sample text [that is working on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WA7vQh/1), but doesn't seem to work in my Jenkins pipeline scenario. So I'm assuming I've got a mistake in my pipeline script, but I fail to see where.

Here's a repro:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo ("Test")

                    output = "Some text. \n\n 12 scenarios (3 failed, 2 success) plus text \n\n and some more text"
                    def hasSummaryMatch = (output ==~ /\d+ scenarios \([^()]+\)/)

                    echo ("hasSummaryMatch = " + hasSummaryMatch)

                    if (!hasSummaryMatch) {
                        error ("No summary!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this with Jenkins 2.60.2 running in the official Docker container.

This provides the following (abbreviated) output:

```
Started by user Administrator
Running on master in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Test001
Test
hasSummaryMatch = false
ERROR: No summary!
Finished: FAILURE
```

The expected output is *no error* because there should be a match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Just use `=~` (the [find operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator)) instead of `==~` (the [match operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator)):

  ```
  def hasSummaryMatch = (output =~ /\d+ scenarios \([^()]+\)/)
  ```
- When match operator `==~` is used, then a strict match of the input string required

Comment: How does this work though?  `==~` returns a boolean, where `=~` returns a `java.util.regex.Matcher`.  Can I expect the matcher to evaluate truthily only when there was a match?  (e.g. `if(matcher)`)

Comment: According to official groovy doc the matcher is true if at least one match found: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#Groovy-Truth

Comment: But this does NOT answer the OP question at all! I WANT strict matching, I use ==~and still, ONLY within Jenkins everything matches to false! Going to use the find operator does not solve this issue!

Comment: what exactly do you think not answered? if you have another question - ask it. in this case the only issue was usage of `==~` instead of `=~`